# Can a public key be exported in PEM format rather than DER format using BouncyCastle?

Tags: rsa, bouncycastle, pem, der

I currently use bouncy castle to generate a RSA key pair and export them into files. Currently, the keys are exported in DER format. I would like to know if it is possible to export them in .PEM format instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your code (which you are not showing) just use [PemWriter](http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/openssl/PEMWriter.html%20PEMWriter).

```
public class PEMWriter
extends org.bouncycastle.util.io.pem.PemWriter
```

Or convert outside with

```
 openssl x509 inform=DER in=in.der outform=PEM out=out.pem
```